# how to use interfaces correctly as DTO in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to create a class with sub classes something like it can be done in `java` and then nest objects, I mean I'm trying to create something like this inside my file `TechnicalInformation.h` are two interfaces where one is inside another as a list

```
@interface Lista : NSObject

    @property (nonatomic) NSString * titulo;

    @property (nonatomic) NSString * medioVerificacion;

    @property (nonatomic) BOOL conDetalle;

    @property (nonatomic) NSString * detalle;

@end



@interface InformacionTecnica : NSObject

    @property NSString * titulo;

    @property NSString * estado;

    @property NSMutableArray<Lista*> * lista;

@end
```

When I try to import the List interface from another file, I try to do something like this

`Lista * list = [Lista new];`

I throw an error at the time of compilation, what would be the correct way to perform this procedure where I want to put it together is a DTO where one interface can be inside another interface and so on and be able to access it from anywhere, I hope I have explained myself well I am using `objective C`

Comment: What is the compile error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add

```
@implementation Lista
@end

@implementation InformacionTecnica 
@end
```

inside your .m file, then it should be working.

Also if your `InformacionTecnica.lista` is an array of `Lista` objects, you could declare it as `NSMutableArray<Lista *> *` for increased type safety.